# GitHub Workflow finish all before `push`

Tags: git, github, github-actions

I am trying to build a workflow to build the package in my repository and `push` it to the GitHub repository.

I used: `os: [ubuntu-20.04, windows-2019, macos-11]` inside the job matrix and this is the final part of the workflow (the repo is checked out using `actions/checkout@v3`):

```
- name: Upload
  run: |
    git config --global user.email "user@gmail.com"
    git config --global user.name "user"
    git add .
    git commit -m "Build"
    git push
```

Here is one problem that I think of:
Suppose the build on Ubuntu completes first. Then it gets to the `Upload` step which uploads the built files to the repository.
Another machine completes its build (say, Windows). When it tries and run `git push`, won't it the repository not up to date error?

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you have 3 jobs (one for each OS) building your project and pushing the build outputs back to the repo. The repo may not be the best place to store build outputs but if that is how you need it done I would do the following:

1. Instead of pushing to the repo in each matrix job instead upload an artifact using [actions/upload-artifact](https://github.com/actions/upload-artifact).

- Make sure to use the OS name in the artifact name so you can tell the 3 apart. This is available via the `RUNNER_OS` [environment variable](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/variables#default-environment-variables).

2. Add an additional job that waits for all 3 matrix jobs to complete.

- In this additional job download all 3 artifacts with [actions/download-artifact](https://github.com/actions/download-artifact)
- Then push all three back to the repo together

Comment: Feasible, may try soon!

Comment: But how can i wait for everything to complete? I can't find it in the documentation

Comment: On job to upload the build outputs you will specify `needs: [job-name]` where job name is the name of your matrix jobs. See [documentation here](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idneeds)

Answer (score -1):

Add git remote origin before push command

**git remote add origin [https://github.com/{username}/{repository-name}](https://github.com/MKhan1792?tab=repositories).git**

Comment: How does this help? Won't the repo checked out already have an origin?